# USB peripherals cutting in and out

Tags: wireless, sound, usb, mouse

I keep having issues with all of my USB peripherals.

The first issue is with my mouse, it jitters every now and again randomly, its a wireless logitech mouse and I have never had an issue on any other distro.

The next is my Logitech UE4500 wireless bluetooth headphones, which came with a USB adapter to use with computers, it detects the headphones fine, but every now and again the sound "jitters" much like the mouse, randomly. Again I have no issues on any other distro or OS.

So I have put this down to a USB issue with Ubuntu. I have Googled for hours but cannot seem to find anything close to my issue.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and update it constantly

Answer (score 0):

I have had USB problems relating to a overloaded power supply.

I have external drives that drop without warning but are easy to get back the original power supply should have had enough total wattage at 300 watts however the 5 Volt was overloaded.

Right now I have put in a 250 Watt power supply just to get it running when the old one lost most of the 5 Volt capability. I have another 300 Watt power supply that I will replace that one with later when I take it apart again look into your power supply to check unplug other USB stuff. If you can and see if the offending peripherals get better. Also I have had conflicts with USB stuff where I had to keep my printer unplugged unless I was using it and it caused other things not to work properly look into that by disconnecting other stuff one thing at a time.

Comment: Please use the formatting options. Also, there can be a multitude of reasons for dropping USB connections. You insinuate that it's a particular and map it to your particular case. Probably not a good idea.

Comment: I only have 2 USB peripherals plugged in, that being my wireless mouse and keyboard.